# How to enter in a another folder in a website

Tags: php, web

I don't know whether it is a correct place to ask this type of question or not.I have a domain name http://www.mycorporateservices.com/ and there is a page which has URL http://www.mycorporateservices.com/Corporate-Services.I want to edit the content of this URL .But when I browse through ftp client,I couldn't find any folder with name Corporate-Services.All the pages have been made in PHP.Thank you for any kind of help.

```
   <?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '1.5.2.1');

// Configuration
require_once('config.php');

// Install 
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: ../install/index.php');
    exit;
}

//VirtualQMOD
require_once('../vqmod/vqmod.php');
$vqmod = new VQMod();

// VQMODDED Startup
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));

// Application Classes
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/currency.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/user.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/weight.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/length.php'));

// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);

// Database
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);

// Settings
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE store_id = '0'");

foreach ($query->rows as $setting) {
    if (!$setting['serialized']) {
        $config->set($setting['key'], $setting['value']);
    } else {
        $config->set($setting['key'], unserialize($setting['value']));
    }
}

// Url
$url = new Url(HTTP_SERVER, $config->get('config_use_ssl') ? HTTPS_SERVER : HTTP_SERVER);   
$registry->set('url', $url);

// Log 
$log = new Log($config->get('config_error_filename'));
$registry->set('log', $log);

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $log, $config;

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_NOTICE:
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            $error = 'Notice';
            break;
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
            $error = 'Warning';
            break;
        case E_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $error = 'Fatal Error';
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Unknown';
            break;
    }

    if ($config->get('config_error_display')) {
        echo '<b>' . $error . '</b>: ' . $errstr . ' in <b>' . $errfile . '</b> on line <b>' . $errline . '</b>';
    }

    if ($config->get('config_error_log')) {
        $log->write('PHP ' . $error . ':  ' . $errstr . ' in ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
    }

    return true;
}

// Error Handler
set_error_handler('error_handler');

// Request
$request = new Request();
$registry->set('request', $request);

// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$registry->set('response', $response); 

// Cache
$cache = new Cache();
$registry->set('cache', $cache); 

// Session
$session = new Session();
$registry->set('session', $session); 

// Language
$languages = array();

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "language"); 

foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $languages[$result['code']] = $result;
}

$config->set('config_language_id', $languages[$config->get('config_admin_language')]['language_id']);

// Language 
$language = new Language($languages[$config->get('config_admin_language')]['directory']);
$language->load($languages[$config->get('config_admin_language')]['filename']); 
$registry->set('language', $language);      

// Document
$registry->set('document', new Document());         

// Currency
$registry->set('currency', new Currency($registry));        

// Weight
$registry->set('weight', new Weight($registry));

// Length
$registry->set('length', new Length($registry));

// User
$registry->set('user', new User($registry));

// Front Controller
$controller = new Front($registry);

// Login
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/home/login'));

// Permission
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/home/permission'));

// Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}

// Dispatch
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));

// Output
$response->output();
?>
```

Comment: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php - open up .htaccess file and search for corporate-services.i or check in database for 'friendly urls'

Comment: It sounds like you've got a content management system, or something else that can translate friendly URLs into something else. All we can do is recommend speaking to the person that set the server up for you.

Comment: Thanks guys for your great suggestions.I have the .htaccess file.I don't have necessary skills to read it.Can you help me out.Thanks

Comment: If you post your .htaccess we can take a look at it - **and by this I mean edit your original post to include the content, don't paste it here in the comments**

Comment: I am providing the .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is clearly an `.htaccess` rewrite going on here so the 'Corporate-Services' is being re-written to something else. Most likely a PHP page.

If you can see a file called `.htaccess`, then I would advise reading this to see what the address is being re-written to. If you do not understand the `.htaccess` file then simply do a search for corporate-services and paste the code in your question.

For more information on `.htaccess` rewrites, take a look at:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

**UPDATE**

Right, your `.htaccess` is rewriting the address to:
[http://www.mycorporateservices.com/index.php?*route*=Corporate-Services](http://www.mycorporateservices.com/index.php?_route_=Corporate-Services)

So, if you would like to edit this file, you need to open 'index.php' and find a condition that tests for something like:

```
if($_GET['_route_']=='Corporate-Services'){
    // Content Here
}
```

Comment: Thanks [Ben Carey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1046010/ben-carey) for your great suggestions.I have the .htaccess file.I don't have necessary skills to read it.Can you help me out.Thanks

Comment: @hridaynehu See my edit! Do a search for corporate-services in the file and paste that snippet into your question :-)

Comment: Getting some problem in uploading .htaccess file

Comment: [Ben Carey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1046010/ben-carey)I have uploaded an image of .htaccess.can you now help me out.Thanks

Comment: There is no image in the question. I would advise just copying and pasting the contents into a code block in your question!

Comment: [Ben CareyI](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1046010/ben-carey)I have inserted a link to snapshot.

Comment: I need to see the whole document! Not just the first 45 lines! :-)

Comment: http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/7720/htaccess1.png[Ben Careyl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1046010/ben-carey)Did you get the file.

Comment: @hridaynehu Yes, just looking at it

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer, if this has helped, dont forget to upvote and accept as the answer! :-)

Comment: [Ben Careyl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1046010/ben-carey)I have looked into index.php but i am been able to find such conditions.Can you help me.There is no such conditions.

Comment: The content is probably dynamically loaded from a database, if this is the case then you are looking in the incorrect place to edit the content. You need to look at the database. However, I would urge you not to as you may edit important data within the database. Can you not ask your web developer to look at this for you?

Comment: Thank you.I will ask my web developer.In the mean time you can see the index.php file.I am editing question for you.

Comment: Sure thing, will take a look :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually URLs do not mimic file system structure [and it's good they do not].

Actuall you could be calling something like:

```
http://www.mycorporateservices.com/index.php/Corporate-Services
```

Then the server knows what to do with the `Corporate-Services` parameter - url is just rewritten by a [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) script.

Go figure what how the installed framework works, but no way to edit a `Corporate-Services/index.php` file of course.

Comment: This is incorrect! The page is not necessarily calling the address you have quoted. It could be calling anything, completely depends on what the .htaccess is rewriting it to!

Comment: You are right, I took for granted he was dealing with a LAMP environment, but nothing states that - thanks for pointing out!

Comment: [Well I was quite close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095745/how-to-convert-friendly-url-to-original-url) :D