# How to convert friendly url to original url

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

I have a URL which has been converted into SEO friendly url using .htaccess.But now i need to find the original url so that i can edit the file and locate it on the web server.The converted friendly url is

Is is possible to get back the original url so that it can be located on the server.Thank you for your suggestions.

.htaccess file view.

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the URL would be

```
http://www.mycorporateservices.com/index.php?_route_=Corporate-Services
```

Opencart uses action and controller to parse the parameters and display the page. You should look for a `<web_app>/controller/module` or `<web_app>/catalog/controller/module` folder and there probably the `Corporate-Services.php`

Comment: Thanks [JScoobyCed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1012381/jscoobyced) for your suggestions.I have done this before and searched my index.php but it does't have anything like this.Can you tell me how to this file on my web server?Thanks

Comment: Opencart uses templates, you should try looking for a `templates` folder or a `controller` folder